# События модели Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Почему если навесить событие через объект events оно не срабатывает, а если забиндить в конструкторе, то все норм?

```
var Row = Backbone.Model.extend({
    modelName: 'Row',
    model: Cell,
    events: {
        'add' : 'ucn',
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.bind('add', this.updateCellNumber, this);
    },
    updateCellNumber: function(cell) {
        cell.set('number', this.length + 1);
    },
    ucn: function(cell) {
        cell.set('number', this.length + 1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поле `events` позволяет задавать обработчики событий *только* для видов (`Backbone.View`). Более того, это поле определяет обработчки для DOM событий, а не для событий самого объекта (см. http://backbonejs.org/#View-events).

Для моделей и коллекций, вам нужно задавать обработчики вручную, например, в методе `initialize` (как это и сделано в вашем примере кода). Так уж устроен Backbone.